# Retrofit API not working in onNavigationItemSelected method and in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit2

Retrofit call.enqueue is not giving any response(success/failure) in Fragement and onNavigationItemSelected  method for BottomNavigationView

In userProfileDetails method i have called Retrofit client. While running the code API response is stuck in call.enqueue method and onResponse or onFailure method not being called in onNavigationItemSelected method
Same method is perfectly working fine onCreate method of respective Activity. Same issue is happening in UserProfileFragment class.

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_landingorder:
                fragment = new OrderFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_reccuringcart:
                fragment = new RecurringCartFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_landingprofile:
                userProfile =userProfileDetails();
                fragment = new UserProfileFragment();

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putSerializable(StringConstants.USERPROFILE, userProfile);
                fragment.setArguments(b);
                break;
        }
        if(fragment!=null){
            displayFragment(fragment);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private UserProfile userProfileDetails() {


        Call<UserProfile> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getUserDetails("Bearer "+ user.get(SessionManager.KEY_SESSION_TOKEN));
        Log.i("user :: " , "Bearer "+ user.get(SessionManager.KEY_SESSION_TOKEN));

        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserProfile>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserProfile> call, Response<UserProfile> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    userProfile = response.body();
                    Log.i("Response SuccessFul :: ", userProfile.getPhoneNo());
                }else {
                    userProfile = response.body();
                    Log.i("Response Failure :: ", userProfile.getPhoneNo());
                    try {

                        Log.e("Coming Inside", String.valueOf(response.code()) + " Err Body " + response.errorBody());
                        Log.i("user :: ", userProfile.getPhoneNo());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Error Inside", String.valueOf(response.code()) + " Err Body " + response.errorBody());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserProfile> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Issues ", t.getMessage() );
            }
        });


        return userProfile;
    }

    private void displayFragment(Fragment fragment){

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.landingrelativeLayout, fragment)
                .commit();

        Toast.makeText(LandingActivity.this, "Display Fragment Home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: try to rename your method for making call, because I think you have a conflict with class-model.

Answer (score 2):

**Your Retrofit ApI run on Thread.**

> Note:- So you will get userProfile `null` everytime. Because that method
>   return before your api is execute.

Do you all work inside `onResponse()` method and make its signature as `void`.

```
 private void userProfileDetails() {


    Call<UserProfile> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getUserDetails("Bearer "+ user.get(SessionManager.KEY_SESSION_TOKEN));
    Log.i("user :: " , "Bearer "+ user.get(SessionManager.KEY_SESSION_TOKEN));

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserProfile>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserProfile> call, Response<UserProfile> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                userProfile = response.body();
                Log.i("Response SuccessFul :: ", userProfile.getPhoneNo());
                // Do your post operation here or after this
            fragment = new UserProfileFragment();

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable(StringConstants.USERPROFILE, userProfile);
            fragment.setArguments(b);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.landingrelativeLayout, fragment)
            .commit();

            }else {
                userProfile = response.body();
                Log.i("Response Failure :: ", userProfile.getPhoneNo());
                try {

                    Log.e("Coming Inside", String.valueOf(response.code()) + " Err Body " + response.errorBody());
                    Log.i("user :: ", userProfile.getPhoneNo());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error Inside", String.valueOf(response.code()) + " Err Body " + response.errorBody());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserProfile> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Issues ", t.getMessage() );
        }
    }); 
}
```

call your method like this .....

```
case R.id.menu_landingprofile:
 userProfileDetails();
break;
```

Comment: No specific error. It is bypassing onResponse and onFailure method. userProfileDetails(); is working absolutely fine in activity.

Comment: Try to put breakpoint inside both onResponse and onFailure method and debug it. You will get it will be bypassing or not ?

Comment: I did that when i am doing through fragment, it is coming out directly from  call.enqueue(new Callback<UserProfile>() and not going inside